# Adjusting font size of map labels in QGIS print layouts

Tags: qgis, print-composer, font

I know how to adjust the font size of shape labels in the main application but is there also a way to adjust them font size of labels in the Print Layout Manager?

At the moment, the labels are too big:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the labels are enabled from the shapefile in the map view, then you need to adjust the labels from the shapefile itself in the map view, then refresh the layout (click the button beside the `Zoom full`) to see the changes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ahmadhanb. I appreciate the time to took to provide a clear animation. It works but is not intuitive, sadly. It doesn't help that there's only one place to control font size but the result is different in both views, as your animation shows. Based on your reputation with QGIS, I guess this is as good as it gets in the current version (3.12.3).